Python - Check if the last value in a sequence is relatively higher than the rest
For a list of percentage data, I need to check if the last value (90.2) is somehow higher and somewhat "abnormal" than the rest of the data. Clearly it is in this sequence.
delivery_pct = [59.45, 55.2, 54.16, 66.57, 68.62, 64.19, 60.57, 44.12, 71.52, 90.2]
But for the below sequnece the last value is not so:
delivery_pct = [ 63.6, 62.64, 60.36, 72.8, 70.86, 40.51, 52.06, 61.47, 51.55, 74.03 ]
How do I check if the last value is abnormally higher than the rest?
About Data: The data point has the range between 0-100%. But since this is percentage of delivery taken for a stock for last 10 days, so it is usually range bound based on nature of stock (highly traded vs less frequently traded), unless something good happens about the stock and there is higher delivery of that stock on that day in anticipation of good news.

do you mean it's higher on average, higher than any other value, or something more exotic like N standard deviations (a common measure of abnormality, though perhaps not in finance)?

Yes, something like that. I tried applying IQR anomaly but I guess that is not appropriate here as the values are range bound.

@RSW I'm not a statistician so don't understand why you think the IQR method is inappropriate. It would certainly produce the result you're looking for

RSW, for all distributions, a criterion defined by a quantile is applicable, e.g. IQR. Criteria defined by mean plus or minus a number of standard deviations are essentially Gaussian approximations, and for non-Gaussian distributions (such as the one you are working with) those will be more or less off the mark.

Once you've determined a threshold (deviation from mean) you could do this:
import statistics

t = 2 # this is the crucial value

pct = [59.45, 55.2, 54.16, 66.57, 68.62, 64.19, 60.57, 44.12, 71.52, 90.2]

mean = statistics.mean(pct)
tsd = statistics.pstdev(pct) * t

lo = mean - tsd
hi = mean + tsd

print(*[x for x in pct if x < lo or x > hi], sep="\n")

Output:
90.2

It's the threshold value that (effectively) determines what's "abnormal"
The interquartile range (IQR) method produces the same result:
import statistics

pct = [59.45, 55.2, 54.16, 66.57, 68.62, 64.19, 60.57, 44.12, 71.52, 90.2]
spct = sorted(pct)
m = len(spct) // 2

Q1 = statistics.median(spct[:m])
m += len(spct) % 2 # increment m if list length is odd
Q3 = statistics.median(spct[m:])

IQR = Q3 - Q1

lo = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
hi = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR

print(*[x for x in pct if x < lo or x > hi], sep="\n")

Output:
90.2


So, that means even in this case IQR test can be applied ?

@RSW I don't think the fact that the values are percentages is relevant so, yes, it appears that IQR is appropriate in this case

You can separate the values by slicing them, but you'll need to know what method by which something is "abnormal"
For example, to compare it to the simple average
def test(data):
    # opportunity to verify length
    earlier = data[:-1]
    last = data[-1]
    avg = sum(earlier) / len(earlier)  # exchange as needed
    return last > avg

NOTE I doubt this simple comparison is sufficient as it fails for your example
The builtin statistics library has a variety of useful methods
The NIST "div898" textbook is an excellent resource for learning about this area too https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/
Or if this is a homework problem, you were likely learning about and/or expressly given a way to work with the data

Let me test with simple average.
